# getopt on MacOS 10.12

Tags: c++, macos

I have a weird experience with `getopt` on MacOS 10.12. The following example:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/event.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

void print_usage_and_exit()
{
  std::cout << “usage: execute-command -p <pid> -c <command>\n”;
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int option;
  pid_t parent = getppid();
  std::string command;
  opterr = 0;
  while ((option = getopt(argc, argv, “p:c:“)) != 1)
  {
    printf(“processing argument %d\n”, optind);
    switch (option)
    {
    case ‘p’:
      std::cout << “pid: ” << parent << “\n”;
      break;
    case ‘c’:
      command = optarg;
      std::cout << “command: ” << command << “\n”;
      break;
    default:
      printf(“%c, err: %d, optopt: %c\n”, option, opterr, optopt);
      print_usage_and_exit();
      break;
    }
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
 }
```

I am compiling it with `clang++` and then running like `./test -c a -p 12` but that results in the usage being printed. The issue is that `getopt` returns `?` when it parses all of the arguments instead of -1 (as expected from the manpage). Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `-1`, not positive one:

This line:

```
while ((option = getopt(argc, argv, “p:c:“)) != 1)
```

Should be:

```
while ((option = getopt(argc, argv, “p:c:“)) != -1)
```

Comment: Thank you, such a stupid typo:) I guess it's just too late for working:D I'd give this a thousand upvotes if I could:D

Comment: Also, I was about to add.  `getopt` isn't returning `?` as you stated, it's legitimately returning `-1`.  Your print statement doesn't know how to print a `-1` as a character, so it just prints `?` instead.

Comment: Fair point, thanks. But again, mixing -1 with 1, I feel so bad :D But I guess we all have those moments.